# Which "front end" for WiX (Windows Installer XML)?

Tags: windows, wix

I am driving through the steep learning curve of this WiX.

Does it exist **a human front-end**? I mean, I find very hard to manage a WiX project, without a book, where it should takes minutes, if there was a simple front end of some sort.
I tried WarSetup and similars but it seems outdated and not aligned, for example it doesn't support localization, which seems to be possibile in the recent WiX build.

I have Orca but that is not a front-end I need.
Tried NVNsomething, not satisfied (it also install a scheduled service?!).

I need a front end like a window where I can better see what the XML does "under the hood".

PS, IMHO: Why MS doesn't invest some $$ into this? Take 10 people and do a front end in 6 months, it that hard and expensive?!??! 
I know that "app stores" are obsoleting the whole concept of an installer, but.... there are big *but*.

Comment: I am reading the book "WiX 3.6 developer guide" but it is 100% code. I think we need more "**graphical tooling**" over this XML.

Comment: Nice - we have to buy a book to have the documentation for something the WIX website should provide for free?

Comment: I feel like there were attempts at integrating WiX into Visual Studio at some point in time, but scheduling issues prevented it.

Comment: It's probably not what you're asking for but... **If you aren't using Visual Studio** or some other editor that assists writing XML based on XSD, you're doing it the really **hard way**.

Comment: There's [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/), [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com/) and Votive (integrated Visual Studio package) to ease it a bit. As for documentation, there are the help files (.chm), the WiX site and the source code. the WiX mailing lists can help out a bunch. I think Rob mentioned something about a GUI editor now that the startup has well, started, but that might be in the distant future. There's not much software to help out with WiX. If you want easy setups, I'd recommend InstallShield or similar.

Comment: I tried all of them, but they are old and immature, practically useless. Votive is ok, but it's just code. We need something like WixEdit, but completely re-designed (I have jumped into the source, it's a winform mess in C# 2.0). We need something like Installshield that sits on top of Wix, like a GUI for Wix projects, that leverages the WiX toolset under the hood. Too bad that Rob started a company to sell custom help for WiX: this means this tool will never come :( Microsoft really abandoned desktop developers, it is unbelieveble.